# How to install a snap package on Raspberry Pi 3B running Ubuntu Core

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi3, snapcraft

I'm trying to install a snap application which I developed using [this](https://snapcraft.io/docs/flutter-applications) link. But when I try to install it on a Raspberry Pi 3B running Ubuntu core, I get the below error.

> error: cannot install snap file: snap "my-flutter-app" supported architectures (amd64) are
> incompatible with this system (arm64)

below is my snapcraft.yaml

```
name: my-flutter-app
version: '1.0'
summary: An example Flutter snap
description: |
  An example showing how Flutter programs can be packaged as snaps.

base: core22
confinement: strict
grade: stable

apps:
  my-flutter-app:
    command: my_flutter_app
    extensions: [gnome]

parts:
  my-flutter-app:
    source: .
    plugin: flutter
    flutter-target: lib/main.dart

    # This appears to be needed when building in the Snap Store.
    build-packages:
      - curl

# Limit the architectures to build for to prevent unnecessary builds on
# architectures that Flutter doesn't support.
architectures:
  - build-on: [amd64]
  - build-on: [arm64]
    build-for: [arm64]
```